# Why vim scp can't read file on my remote vps?

Tags: ssh

Password-free ssh authentication had been set.
There is a file `/home/test.txt` in my remote_ip.

```
vim scp://root@remote_ip//home/test.txt
```

Why vim  scp  can't read file on my remote vps?

```
vim  --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Sep 30 2017 18:21:38)
ls -al   /home/test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 100 Apr 23 12:40 /home/test.txt
enough space left on both local and remote device.
ssh credential established between my vps and local pc.
```

To connect with my vps.

```
ssh  -i .ssh/id_rsa  -p 1000  root@remote_ip
```

The port number is 1000 not standard 22.

Comment: Without any information at all it will be extremely hard to give any meaningful answer to this. Basically your question is just "it doesn't work". Okay ... but what are the results? What are your settings? etc Even *with* all information, this is a very difficult problem to solve over the internet, as there are just so many variables involved. your best bet is really to look at the ssh logs etc. *yourself* and debug from there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not contain nearly enough information to give a meaningful answer. Please see e.g. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1325/51)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I'm blind shooting here, but here are some ideas

- You have older vim version than 6.
- The remote file is not readable
- No space left on the local device.
- Local firewall blocks the outgoing connection
- Remote firewall blocks the connection
- Your ssh public key is not in the `authorized_keys` file on remote
- Your local ssh keys are not in the default folder `.ssh`

You may want to debug your ssh connection first with `ssh xy@remote -vvv` to find out if the connection can be established.

Comment: Connection can be established  with `ssh  -i .ssh/id_rsa  -p 1000  root@remote_ip`

Comment: @it_is_a_literature do you specify the port? You can create an entry in `~/.ssh/config`, use `vim scp://root@remote_ip:1000//home/test.txt` or `let g:netrw_scp_cmd="scp -q -P 1000"`.